# OAuth 2 password grant using sso

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am implementing an oauth 2 setup and have a use case that I am not quite sure how it applies to oauth 2. Hopefully someone here can set me on the right track.

My platform consists of an api that I want to access from a mobile app. As I control both the app and api and also have users owning the data I figured the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant grant would fit in nicely.
However on the app I want the user for now to only login via facebook. When I receive the uid and access token from facebook I would create a new user or update a current user in my api. A password wouldn't be set in this process and as the password grant requires a username and password to get the access token my problem becomes apparent.

So, what would be good practice for this use case? Should I create a password for the user or maybe send the facebook token as a valid password credential that is validated in the api? Or maybe a different grant type is better suited?

Appreciate any feedback!

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question. Unfortunately I don't know the answer. If I find something I will report back.